# PostgreSQL/Metabase: How to create variable to filter by multiple numbers

Tags: sql, postgresql, filter, concatenation, metabase

I would like to filter by multiple ids (e.g. item ids of purchases). The following line of code does not seem to do the trick either for number or text variables (e.g. user names). How should I write this line of code so in the filtering field I could type my values separated by a comma and look for entries that contain either of the item ids I have provided? How would that line of code differ if wanting to apply a filter by a text variable instead (i.e. user name)?

`[[where "User name" like concat('%',{{user_name}},'%')]]`

Comment: Text: `[[where "User name" ~ any (string_to_array({{user_names}},','))]]`, integer: `[[where "Id" = any (string_to_array({{id_list}},',')::integer[])]]`

Answer (score -1):

Use a field filter parameter, mapping it to the id column and it's respective table
Then structure your query like below:

```
select * from profiles where user_name ({{PARAM}})
```

Documentation: https://www.metabase.com/learn/sql-questions/field-filters